# Split dataframe depending on an attribute

Tags: python

I have a question about splitting a dataframe. I want the grouping of data to be done according to a given attribute.

**For example:** I have an attribute `x` which is either `<0.5 or> 0.5`.
So I want clustering to give me two groups,

1. One of data that have as x <0.5
2. The other group where x> 0.5

Is there a solution? thank you

Comment: Add an example please

Comment: The solution is pretty straightfoward, at least for your example...

Comment: How do you store data? If you use pandas, you can do something like `df['column'] = (df['x'] < 0.5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is about basic programming technique.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=50)
print('Original Values')
print(x)

groupA = []
groupB = []

for xitem in x:
    if xitem <= 0.5:
        groupA.append(xitem)
    else:
        groupB.append(xitem)

print('group A')
print(groupA)
print('group B')
print(groupB)
```

Gives you:

```
Original Values
[0.32589696 0.05144454 0.3185115  0.44712084 0.41648028 0.83977423
 0.54061874 0.05583937 0.93067456 0.41763108 0.70905716 0.94582328
 0.9932486  0.06834    0.54789265 0.68866598 0.47188399 0.62864056
 0.04820358 0.21935119 0.5146725  0.40023542 0.97429373 0.24902844
 0.39409913 0.96247417 0.57696844 0.67546141 0.79400894 0.44830457
 0.29500037 0.77739617 0.53539312 0.75193549 0.22002909 0.19796147
 0.1739707  0.40734209 0.10614055 0.43634519 0.24865746 0.43886737
 0.54361849 0.21692039 0.33623253 0.01805197 0.71022451 0.52776778
 0.16213003 0.78893891]
group A
[0.325896959384964, 0.0514445444953352, 0.3185115042135239, 0.447120840309126, 0.41648028298259887, 0.05583936914128218, 0.41763107913224073, 0.06833999667958424, 0.47188398978792234, 0.04820357539733733, 0.21935118588188507, 0.4002354236237443, 0.24902843579302625, 0.3940991273818705, 0.4483045722482677, 0.2950003683766097, 0.22002909264547388, 0.19796146580392382, 0.17397069583620484, 0.40734208646363645, 0.10614054933682493, 0.43634519025046536, 0.2486574594683204, 0.4388673670602017, 0.2169203865405519, 0.3362325296591817, 0.01805196793659747, 0.16213002704108503]
group B
[0.8397742323096252, 0.540618735072025, 0.9306745584875667, 0.7090571559979788, 0.9458232841023849, 0.9932485951266484, 0.5478926512185291, 0.6886659807258041, 0.6286405561999165, 0.5146724961600602, 0.9742937336700853, 0.962474172144148, 0.5769684433064299, 0.6754614108084783, 0.7940089394834825, 0.7773961745651656, 0.5353931179563641, 0.7519354929404076, 0.5436184941517485, 0.7102245133044452, 0.5277677794818838, 0.7889389082699289]
```

At the end, `group A` has all the values less than or equals to `0.5` and `group B` contains all the others. Is this what you are asking?

**Edit after your comment**
As PV8 also suggested in the answer:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x', 'y'])
df1['x'] = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=50)
df1['y'] = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=50)

df1['group'] = np.where(df1['x'] < 0.5, "A", "B")

fig1 = px.scatter(df1,x="x", y="y", color="group")
fig1.update_layout(height=600, width=800, title_text="Subplots")
fig1.show()
```

This gives you two groups clustered and visualized in a scatter plot.
[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes it is a solution but I wanted to apply with the clustering approach to visualize the results as a cluster

Comment: You can edit your question or post the error as comment here.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is quite easy, you can definie a new column, and add `np.where`to it:

```
import numpy as np
#your dataframe is df, with the column 'attribute'

df['group'] = np.where(df['attribute'] < 0.5, "A", "B")
```

This will give you a new column `group`, which will have a "A" inside, if the atrritube value is less then `0.5`and otherwise a "B".